# jQuery dialog Open link in same page

Tags: jquery, url, hyperlink, dialog

I have a dialog with 2 buttons 'cancel' and 'open', when I click on open I would like to load a url in the same page.

This is my code:

```
$("#delete_wind").dialog({ autoOpen: false })   
    $( "#delete_wind" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:'auto',
        width:350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {"OPEN Message": function() {
        url=('mailbox.php?id='+jQuery.data(document.body, 'elimina_id'));

            **HOW OPEN URL??????**
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );

            },
            "Annulla": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can just set the `window.location.href` attribute:

```
location.href = '/' + 'mailbox.php?id='+jQuery.data(document.body, 'elimina_id');
```

Comment: Drat!  Beat me by 39 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the URL inside the dialog, try this:

```
$("#delete_wind").dialog({ autoOpen: false })   
    $( "#delete_wind" ).dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:'auto',
        width:350,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {"OPEN Message": function() {
        url=('mailbox.php?id='+jQuery.data(document.body, 'elimina_id'));

            $.get('yoururl.php'.function(data){
                 $('#delete_wind').html(data);
            });
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );

            },
            "Annulla": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
});
```